# Android fastindex scroll recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to disable the swipe gesture in alphabetical order of myinnos index fast scroll recyclerview. only on click needs to work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
This isn't a free code writing service.
Neither is it a replacement for tutorials or web searches.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/myinnos/AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView

I think this is the one that you are looking for, try this one it's worked for me...

Comment: This is the one i am using in my project. In this i need to disable the alphabets swipe  listeners. I want that to be in click listener.